# TextField events in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to call my method in fxml file after user click on text field, but see exception:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

My fxml tag:

```
<TextField fx:id="userId"  onMouseClicked="#processEnter" />
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the parameter type for `processEnter(...)` is `MouseEvent`, and that you have the correct import in the controller: `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`, not the awt version.